# Lifecycle never pass through onCreate

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2

I have two computers, both with same hardware and Android Studio settings.
When I build the app on the first, the app works well, but when I build the app on the second, some parts of the app lifecycle just don't work.
Example: the app never pass through the onCreate()

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Matheos welcome to Stackoverflow!!

As for solution, try to Clean Project and then rebuild on second one PC.

[image]